# ExtJS form model and reader

Tags: json, forms, data-binding, extjs

I want to bind data to my form from JSON reader using Ext JS 4.
Structure of JSON looks like this:

```
[
{"form[name]":"John","form[city]":"Dublin"},{"form[name]":"Deborah","form[city]":"London"}
]
```

but my reader and model doesn't parse it.
Model:

```
Ext.define('contact', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'form[name]'},
            {name: 'form[city]'}
        ]
    });
```

Reader:

```
reader : Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Json', {
            model: 'contact'
        }),
```

Bind:

```
myFormPanel.getForm().load({
                    url: 'data.json'
})
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A few things: your returned JSON doesn't seem to have a (data) root. It appears to be a list of records rather than a single record. Also, where is the reader configured?

Comment: reader is configured in Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', { /* here the code of form, with reader */ })

Comment: But `Ext.form.Panel` doesn't have a reader config.

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/xml-form.js
Move to line var formPanel=...

Comment: Do those seem like sensible property names to you?